# TYPO 3 11.5 : tables not created for my new extension

Tags: typo3

I followed this guide for creating my own extension : https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/11.5/en-us/4-FirstExtension/4-make-products-persistent.html

I used extension builder for creating the skeleton of my extension but I created the file ext_tables.sql myself and I filled it like that :

```
CREATE TABLE tx_myextension_domain_model_product (
   title varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
   reference int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
   description text NOT NULL
);
```

I created the TCA file and locallang but now I can't create product and the table wasn't created :

I tried to check in Maintenance -> Analyze Database Structure but I can't see my fields

My ext_tables.php is empty

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3') or die('Access denied.');
```

Does this have anything to do with my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added your ext_tables.sql code to my custom extension, and it works as expected. I don't have an ext_tables.php. You can delete it if you want to, it should not matter.

Did you check, the extension is installed and active (via extension manager)

Comment: I didn't started the frontend part of the extension, I'm still supposed to see the extension in the extension manager? 
I checked and I didn't see my extension to the list of extensions